# Consecutive numbers that share the same sum of prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $f(n)$ denote the sum of the prime factors of $n$ (with multiplicity).

I have been looking for pairs of consecutive numbers $n,n+1$ such that $f(n)=f(n+1)$.

Case #$1$:

- $f(8)=f(2\cdot2\cdot2)=2+2+2=6$
- $f(9)=f(3\cdot3)=3+3=6$

Case #$2$:

- $f(15)=f(3\cdot5)=3+5=8$
- $f(16)=f(2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2)=2+2+2+2=8$

Are these the only two such pair of numbers to exist?

I think that it might be related to [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Comment: Related to Catalan's conjecture how? How far have you searched?

Comment: @daniel: Not very far, as it becomes increasingly hard (on the computational aspect). But in every equivalence class (for example, class $8=\{15,16,18\}$), the differences seem to become larger and larger. Related to Catalan's conjecture in a very "associative" way - the pair of numbers $8$ and $9$ are also there.

Comment: How far is "not very far?"

Comment: As you have a second example, I don't think there'll be any relation to Catalan's conjecture.

Comment: There are also $f(5)=f(6)=5$ and  $f(77)=f(78)=18$.

Comment: @WChargin: Thanks. The answer below also mentions that.

Comment: @barakmanos: I don't mean to be rude, but you missed 5 and factorising all numbers to 78 isn't difficult. I therefore advise that you learn a simple programming language (for example Python or Mathematica) and use it to quickly attack this kind of question for small numbers :-)

Comment: Mathematica is very good for this purpose. It lists the first 200000 values of f in about 10 seconds. With a little extra effort you could get it to find pairs $f(n+1)=f(n).$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that $f(5) = 5 = 2 + 3 = f(2 \cdot 3) = f(6)$, so $(5, 6)$ is another such pair.

There are more, too: The pairs $(n, n + 1)$, $n < 1000$, that satisfy the criteria are
$$(5, 6), (8, 9), (15, 16), (77, 78), (125, 126), (714, 715), (948, 949).$$
This (or perhaps the sequence of $n$) is the [*Ruth–Aaron sequence*](https://oeis.org/A039752), so named because of the [significance of those players w.r.t. the numbers $714$ and $715$ in baseball history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_top_300_Major_League_Baseball_home_run_hitters). For more terms, see [this list of the first $10^5$ $n$ satisfying the condition](https://oeis.org/A039752/b039752.txt), or [this list of the $\sim 4.4 \cdot 10^5$ pairs with $n < 10^{13}$](http://chesswanks.com/seq/a039752.txt), including prime factorizations (the latter is a large file, obviously).

It's apparently not known whether there are infinitely many such pairs ([a large such $n$](http://chesswanks.com/num/ALargeRuthAaronPair.txt) apparently has $3108$ digits), but this would follow from [Schinzel's Hypothesis H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H); see [Ruth–Aaron Numbers Revisited](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ecarlp/PDF/paper130.pdf) (C. Pomerance), which also gives the asymptotic upper bound of $O\left(\frac{n \log^4 \log n}{\log^2 n}\right)$ Ruth–Aaron number $\leq n$ as $n \to \infty$. (This bound is strong enough to ensure that the sum of reciprocals of Ruth–Aaron Numbers is bounded.)

There are also triples $(n, n + 1, n + 2)$ such that $f(n) = f(n + 1) = f(n + 2)$; the smallest of these is given by $n = 417\,162$, for which $f(n) = 533$. It's not known whether any quadruplets exist.

See this [related MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191386/ruth-aaron-triples-etc).

Comment: Thank you for the highly detailed answer. As I've already mentioned in a comment to the previous answer, my question seems really dumb now... But both answers are very good, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it helpful.

Comment: I wonder if there is a limit for the largest prime factor, relative to the size of the number. Probably relative to the square root of the number.

Comment: @gnasher729 Of course, $5$ itself is prime, but there are no other primes in any pair for $n \leq 10^6$. I am no expert in this area, but probably it is hard to say much about the asymptotic behavior of largest prime factors.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are many more. These are the ones smaller than 10000:
$$
5,8,15,77,125,714,948,1330,1520,1862,2491,3248,\\
4185,4191,5405,5560,5959,6867,8280,8463
$$
Some more data: there are 149 with $n<10^6$ and 523 with $n<10^7$.

Comment: Hmmm... My question seems really dumb now (comment by @daniel makes more sense reading it again). Thanks.